# Is this unit test more readable when repeating some code?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

We had a discussion in our team about two possible versions of a unit test.

Version 1:

```
var dependencyMock = new Mock<IDependency>();
dependencyMock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething()).Returns("some string");
var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(dependency.Object);

var result = classUnderTest.DoSomethingElse();

Assert.AreEqual("some string", result);
```

Version 2:

```
string expectedResult = "some string";
var dependencyMock = new Mock<IDependency>();
dependencyMock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething()).Returns(expectedResult);
var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(dependency.Object);

var result = classUnderTest.DoSomethingElse();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
```

The discussion was about if the "some string" should be duplicated (Version 1) or if it should be put in a variable (Version 2). We all agreed on that some code duplication is fine in unit tests, if it makes the test more readable. For me, Version 1 is more readable (for my colleague Version 2 is more readable). For me it seems in terms of readability, neither is better.

Are there any other arguments for one of the versions? 
(I am not sure, if this question is valid to be asked here, because it might lead to a discussion and there might be no "answer"...)

Comment: this is opinion based for sure, anyway maybe can be a good idea thinking about the mantenaince of the unit tests

Comment: testing various aspect of the same class, the unit tests tend to be very repetitive, full of same boilerplates.
So refactoring of the unit tests can be usefull to obtain human-readable tests.

Comment: In this special case, ClassUnderTest simply forwards the return value of IDependency.DoSomething(), right? What if ClassUnderTest should change the string and return the modified string? In this case it would be easier to maintain the test when there is no variable (as in Version 2). One more thing: Do the two strings have the same meaning? I think you can already see by the name of the variable _expectedResult_ that it has different meanings for IDependency and ClassUnderTest.

Comment: My comment its related to the meaning of the refactory of unit tests, not of your specific case, I think simply this question is off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Code duplication is often good in unit tests because it shows you in a glimpse what is being done, but in this case your duplication is actually a negative thing.

The most important argument is that version 2 makes sure you won't accidentally have different strings. It's a good habit to get into when you also have this situation with different, more complex objects.